# How do I fill soffit gap?

Tags: soffit

Had house rendered but this piece of soffit has been knocked off! What's best way to repair it? This is on the apex of the roof. Thanks

Comment: Hi Sarah,  how aboug a photo

Comment: Please[Edit] your question and click the "sun & mountains" button to insert a pic into your question. Make sure the text cursor is positioned where you want the pic to appear in your question before you click the button.